# Forcing OrbitControls to navigate around a moving object (almost working)

Tags: three.js

I am learning Three.js and I am playing with the model of solar system to learn how it works. So I have a scene in which the Earth rotates around the Sun, and the Moon around the Earth.

Now I would like to focus on the Moon and use controls to rotate around it (while having it all the time in the center of the screen). OrbitControls seem to be ideal for that, but I cannot get them to work with the moving Moon.

Here are my 3 attempts (please ignore that the Earth and the Moon are cubes).

#### Attempt 1 - Placing camera ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lguminski/c4p7o8k9/5/))

First, I created a scene where `camera` is a child of the Moon (without OrbitControls).

```
moon.add(camera);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
```

```js
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, labelRenderer;
var solarPlane, earth, moon;
var angle = 0;

function buildScene() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  solarPlane = createSolarPlane();
  earth = createBody("Earth");
  moon = createBody("Moon");

  scene.add(solarPlane);
  solarPlane.add(earth);
  earth.add(moon);

  moon.add(camera);
}

init();
animate();

function init() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: false
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
  labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(13.670839104116506, 10.62941701834559, 0.3516419193657562);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  buildScene();
}

function animate(time) {

  angle = (angle + .005) % (2 * Math.PI);
  rotateBody(earth, angle, 1);
  rotateBody(moon, angle, 2);

  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  function rotateBody(body, angle, radius) {
    body.rotation.x = angle;
    body.position.x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
    body.position.y = radius * Math.sin(angle);
    body.position.z = radius * Math.sin(angle);
  }
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  labelRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createBody(name, parent) {
  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  const body = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  body.position.set(1, 1, 1);
  body.scale.set(.3, .3, .3);
  body.name = name;
  body.add(makeTextLabel(name));
  return body;
}

function createSolarPlane() {
  var solarPlane = new THREE.GridHelper(5, 10);
  solarPlane.add(makeTextLabel("solar plane"));
  return solarPlane;
}

function makeTextLabel(label) {
  var text = document.createElement('div');
  text.style.color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  text.textContent = label;
  return new THREE.CSS2DObject(text);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
```

**Result:** it nicely puts the Moon in the center, but obviously you cannot navigate the scene, because I haven't employed `OrbitControls` yet. But this attempt acts as a reference.

#### Attempt 2 - Adding OrbitControls ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lguminski/g4spk2ad/))

Then I added `OrbitControls`.

```js
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, labelRenderer;
var solarPlane, earth, moon;
var angle = 0;

function buildScene() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  solarPlane = createSolarPlane();
  earth = createBody("Earth");
  moon = createBody("Moon");

  scene.add(solarPlane);
  solarPlane.add(earth);
  earth.add(moon);

  moon.add(camera);
}

init();
animate();

function init() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: false
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
  labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(13.670839104116506, 10.62941701834559, 0.3516419193657562);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  buildScene();

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enablePan = false;
  controls.enableDamping = false;
}

function animate(time) {

  angle = (angle + .005) % (2 * Math.PI);
  rotateBody(earth, angle, 1);
  rotateBody(moon, angle, 2);

  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  function rotateBody(body, angle, radius) {
    body.rotation.x = angle;
    body.position.x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
    body.position.y = radius * Math.sin(angle);
    body.position.z = radius * Math.sin(angle);
  }
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  labelRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createBody(name, parent) {
  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  const body = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  body.position.set(1, 1, 1);
  body.scale.set(.3, .3, .3);
  body.name = name;
  body.add(makeTextLabel(name));
  return body;
}

function createSolarPlane() {
  var solarPlane = new THREE.GridHelper(5, 10);
  solarPlane.add(makeTextLabel("solar plane"));
  return solarPlane;
}

function makeTextLabel(label) {
  var text = document.createElement('div');
  text.style.color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  text.textContent = label;
  return new THREE.CSS2DObject(text);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
```

**Result:** the Moon has been moved from the center to the side (no idea why?). And when you start navigating with the mouse, everything goes crazy. The effect is as if `OrbitControls` navigates around the center of the scene and the camera around its parent (the Moon). Effectively they don't change state in a consistent manner, and everything goes wild.

#### Attempt 3 - Controlling Orbits' target ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lguminski/y097hpae/))

Last option I tried was to forcefully set `controls.target` so that it always points at the Moon. Because the Moon constantly moves around, I had to do it before each rendering.

```
const p = new THREE.Vector3();
const q = new THREE.Quaternion();
const s = new THREE.Vector3();
moon.matrixWorld.decompose(p, q, s);

// now setting controls target to Moon's position (in scene's coordinates)
controls.target.copy(p); 

render();
```

```js
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, labelRenderer;
var solarPlane, earth, moon;
var angle = 0;
const p = new THREE.Vector3();
const q = new THREE.Quaternion();
const s = new THREE.Vector3();

function buildScene() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  solarPlane = createSolarPlane();
  earth = createBody("Earth");
  moon = createBody("Moon");

  scene.add(solarPlane);
  solarPlane.add(earth);
  earth.add(moon);

  moon.add(camera);
}

init();
animate();

function init() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: false
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
  labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(13.670839104116506, 10.62941701834559, 0.3516419193657562);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  buildScene();

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enablePan = false;
  controls.enableDamping = false;
}

function animate(time) {

  angle = (angle + .005) % (2 * Math.PI);
  rotateBody(earth, angle, 1);
  rotateBody(moon, angle, 2);

  moon.matrixWorld.decompose(p, q, s);
  controls.target.copy(p);

  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  function rotateBody(body, angle, radius) {
    body.rotation.x = angle;
    body.position.x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
    body.position.y = radius * Math.sin(angle);
    body.position.z = radius * Math.sin(angle);
  }
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  labelRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createBody(name, parent) {
  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  const body = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  body.position.set(1, 1, 1);
  body.scale.set(.3, .3, .3);
  body.name = name;
  body.add(makeTextLabel(name));
  return body;
}

function createSolarPlane() {
  var solarPlane = new THREE.GridHelper(5, 10);
  solarPlane.add(makeTextLabel("solar plane"));
  return solarPlane;
}

function makeTextLabel(label) {
  var text = document.createElement('div');
  text.style.color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  text.textContent = label;
  return new THREE.CSS2DObject(text);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
```

**Result:** Initially the Moon is located on the side of the screen (same position as in the second attempt), but then when you start navigate, the Moon "jumps" to the center of the screen, and you can navigate around it. Almost perfect. As long you don't zoom. When you zoom in/zoom out, you start seeing that the Moon rotates during the zooming action.

#### Questions

1. why does `OrbitControls` not respect the fact that camera's parent is the Moon, and keeps navigating around the center of the scene?
2. why did the Moon "jump" to the side of the screen after adding `OrbitControls`?
3. what would be the elegant way of making it work? (forcing `target` to follow the Moon in a loop is neither elegant nor working due to the zooming issue)?

r. 98

**Edit:** editorial changes to make a sentence more clear.
**Edit:** upgrade to three.js r. 109.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made it work by introducing a fake camera, which has everything the same as the original camera, except for `camera.parent`

```
fakeCamera = camera.clone(); // parent becomes null
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(fakeCamera, renderer.domElement);
```

This way `OrbitControls` has a camera with its own coordinate system.

Then, before rendering, I copy `fakeCamera`'s values back to the real camera, which is used for rendering.

```
camera.position.copy(fakeCamera.position);
camera.quaternion.copy(fakeCamera.quaternion);
camera.scale.copy(fakeCamera.scale);

render();
```

and it works well.

**EDIT**

I noticed that

```
camera.position.copy(fakeCamera.position);
camera.quaternion.copy(fakeCamera.quaternion);
camera.scale.copy(fakeCamera.scale);
```

can be replaced with

```
camera.copy(fakeCamera);
```

(the code below has been updated accordingly)

```js
var camera, fakeCamera, controls, scene, renderer, labelRenderer;
var solarPlane, earth, moon;
var angle = 0;

function buildScene() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  solarPlane = createSolarPlane();
  earth = createBody("Earth");
  moon = createBody("Moon");

  scene.add(solarPlane);
  solarPlane.add(earth);
  earth.add(moon);

  moon.add(camera);
}

init();
animate();

function init() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: false
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
  labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(13.670839104116506, 10.62941701834559, 0.3516419193657562);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  buildScene();

  fakeCamera = camera.clone();
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(fakeCamera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enablePan = false;
  controls.enableDamping = false;
}

function animate(time) {

  angle = (angle + .005) % (2 * Math.PI);
  rotateBody(earth, angle, 1);
  rotateBody(moon, angle, 2);

  camera.copy(fakeCamera);

  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  function rotateBody(body, angle, radius) {
    body.rotation.x = angle;
    body.position.x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
    body.position.y = radius * Math.sin(angle);
    body.position.z = radius * Math.sin(angle);
  }
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  labelRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createBody(name, parent) {
  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  const body = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  body.position.set(1, 1, 1);
  body.scale.set(.3, .3, .3);
  body.name = name;
  body.add(makeTextLabel(name));
  return body;
}

function createSolarPlane() {
  var solarPlane = new THREE.GridHelper(5, 10);
  solarPlane.add(makeTextLabel("solar plane"));
  return solarPlane;
}

function makeTextLabel(label) {
  var text = document.createElement('div');
  text.style.color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  text.textContent = label;
  return new THREE.CSS2DObject(text);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solution is working, but actually it is a workaround. There was a discussion on how to fix it at the level of three.js, but eventually my PR didn't get through. Nevertheless it was an interesting discussion. So in case you are interested
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/15267
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15268

Comment: (there is more under the PR)

Answer (score 0):

I think your workaround is a nice solution because it does not require modifying imported code. Also, an extra camera is not expensive to maintain as long as it is not used for rendering. Here is an OrbitControls subclass that can be applied, based on the same principle. Note that the `localTarget` property is just an alias for the `target` property. There is no `globalTarget` property.

```
THREE.OrbitControlsLocal = function ( realObject, domElement ) {
    this.realObject = realObject;
    //Camera and Object3D have different forward direction:
    let placeholderObject = realObject.isCamera ? new THREE.PerspectiveCamera() : new THREE.Object3D;
    this.placeholderObject = placeholderObject;

    THREE.OrbitControls.call( this, placeholderObject, domElement );

    let globalUpdate = this.update;
    this.globalUpdate = globalUpdate;
    this.update = function() {

        //This responds to changes made to realObject from outside the controls:
        placeholderObject.position.copy( realObject.position );
        placeholderObject.quaternion.copy( realObject.quaternion);
        placeholderObject.scale.copy( realObject.scale );
        placeholderObject.up.copy( realObject.up );

        var retval = globalUpdate();
        realObject.position.copy( placeholderObject.position );
        realObject.quaternion.copy( placeholderObject.quaternion);
        realObject.scale.copy( placeholderObject.scale );
        return retval ;

    };

    this.update();
};

THREE.OrbitControlsLocal.prototype = Object.create(THREE.OrbitControls.prototype);
THREE.OrbitControlsLocal.prototype.constructor = THREE.OrbitControlsLocal;

Object.defineProperties(THREE.OrbitControlsLocal.prototype, {
    localTarget: {
        get: ()=>this.target,
        set: v=>this.target=v
    }
});
```

My previous solution of merely converting the local target to world space before applying lookAt was not correct. The problem seems to be that lookAt orients the camera according to its world-space up direction (camera.up or object.up) on every update. This problem does not exist with the placeholder/fakeCamera solution. (See PR https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/16374)

Comment: Your code seems to nicely wrap and hide the workaround. BTW If lookAt() would not reorient world-space up direction of the looking object, then not only your previous solution would work, but in fact it wouldn't be even needed, because threejs would work properly out of the box. That was the essence of my PR https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15268#issuecomment-440258890

Comment: The three.js OrbitControls still wouldn't work in local space out of the box, as long as lookAt points to a world space position.

Comment: Correct. This is the second problem.